# GcmTaskService execution order

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-service

I could not find a single word about the execution order of multiple scheduled tasks in the `GcmTaskService` documentation. Especially in combination with `RESULT_RESCHEDULE`.

Which strategy does the `GcmTaskService` implement and on what behavior can I rely on?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never found the answer and implemented my own queue

Answer (score 0):

You may implement '*onRunTask*()' to override this function to provide the logic for your task execution. Bear in mind that your service may receive calls from the scheduler at once (specifically if you have made multiple schedule requests that overlap). Your implementation of your 'onRunTask' must be thread safe. It will determine what the manager does with subsequent executions of task. You can return *RESULT_RESCHEDULE* to have this task be re-executed again shortly subject to e*xponential back-off.*

Here's the documentation demonstrate the Implementation of GCM Network Manager on Android which include Schedule Tasks: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager#schedule_tasks